# What is the meaning of "-" (minus) in this bash command?

Tags: bash

Could somebody explain to me what is the meaning of the `-` (minus) sign in the following command?

```
wget -O - "https://www.some-domain.com/file.tar.gz" | tar xzf -
```

Comment: hope it helps mate


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41828/what-does-dash-at-the-end-of-a-command-mean

Comment: that was most helpful and comprehensive @ferozakbar. thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`-`  depends on the command and how it responds to it. but it usually means the stdout/stdin in bash commands.

In this case, `-` is the argument to the `-O` option, so
the downloaded data is not saved in a file, but printed to stdout, so it can be piped to the tar command

Comment: **Not always**, it depends on the command and how it responds on the `-`. But in this case you are right.

Comment: More explicitly: that's a *common* convention but it's not something that's enforced by the shell. *Many* programs follow that convention, but not all do.

Comment: i edited the answer to be more accurate (based on the comments). thanks guys.

Comment: @Veger: But it *should* be always. When I find a program that access files and does not treat - as stdout/in, I fill a bug report for it...